# How to change route from oauth/authenticate to oauth/authorize in Omni auth gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

I am using Omni auth gem to load twitter feeds into my application.
But when i try to load direct messages, its not letting the application to direct messages.

I researched and found that when adding a twitter account, usually the system takes us to

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate
```

but i found my applicatin could access direct message when the request made to twitter during twitter account add process will be like below

```
https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize
```

where do i configure this in Omniauth gem?
Please give me a hand on this.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by adding `client_options: {authorize_path: '/oauth/authorize'}` 
under config/initializers/omniauth.rb under provider :twitter.